# Inequality for determining sign of a variable with respect to another

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming

Let $a$ and $b$ be two integer variables. We have to model the following two relations:

- $b=1$ when $a > 0$, and
- $b=0$ when $a = 0$.

We should use inequalities and **avoid** non-linear relationships between them. I've tried $a \ge M\cdot b$ where $M$ is a huge number, but this is incorrect since $b$ can still be 1 when $a = 0$, which should not be possible according to the previous definition.

Comment: Can you state the actual problem verbatim? Fully stated please, indicating all restrictions on the variables (e.g., are the variables integers or just reals?; is $a$ required to be nonnegative?). As stated, your question is too vague. If the problem is from a book, indicate which book, which problem.

Comment: It's not from a book. It's a problem that I have encountered with in a linear regression problem (which is too long as to publish it here). The variables are integers. And, yes, we are talking about the N set (for both $a$ and $b$).

Comment: It can be interpreted as an integer linear programming problem: Maximize $b$ subject to the constraints $a,b \ge 0,\;\;\;b\le a,\;\;\;b \le 1$.

Comment: I don't want to maximize anything. I just want to satisfy several conditions.

Comment: Well, if you have an upper bound on $a$, it can be made to work.

Comment: Do you only consider non-negative integers (since there is no constraint on $b$ for $a<0$)? If yes, then we can solve this problem as follows. Let $b$ be a binary, i.e., $b \in \{0,1\}$ (If this is not possible you can just add $0\leq b \leq 1$). Then $a > 0 \Rightarrow b=1$ is modeled by $b \cdot M \geq a$ where $M$ is a huge number (at least as large as the maximum value of $a$). $a = 0 \Rightarrow b=0$ is obtained by $b \leq a$.

Comment: Notice that your conclusion that $b$ can be positive when $a=0$ is incorrect.